# Sort sublist based on the ordering of superlist

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Suppose we have the list `[3,7,2,8,1,9,4]` and the sublist `[4,1,7,9]`.

We want to sort the sublist such that the ordering of its elements becomes the same as the ordering of the same elements in the superlist.

`[4,1,7,9] -> [7,1,9,4]`

What is an efficient and elegant way of achieving this in Java?

Comment: The downvote is not from me though I think the [4,1,7,9] should not be called "sublist". For users of Java collection API sublist is what is called subsequence in math. [4,1,7,9] is just a list whose set of elements is subset of set of elements of other list. (Which arises further questions on duplicate elements but that another story.)

Comment: @TomášZáluský, thanks for explaining. I should have mentioned that the list will have distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also assuming that `list` and `subList` are of type `ArrayList` but using the java8 strean api.

```
var list = List.of(3,7,2,8,1,9,4);
var subList = List.of(4,1,7,9);

var orderedList = subList.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(list::indexOf))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Assuming the `subList` is declared as mutable (`new ArrayList<>(List.of ...)`), you can sort in-place without using streams - just use `Collections2.sort`. Also note that due to repeated call of `indexOf` the asymptotic time complexity is not optimal - precomputing indexes into map would improve it.

Comment: I ended up using `sublist.sort(Comparator.comparing(list::indexOf))`. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: comment bugfix: I meant java.util.Collections.sort

Answer (score 1):

i assume that `list` and `sublist` is `arrayList`

```java
list.forEach(l -> {
    var index = Iterables.indexOf(subList, s -> s == l);
    if (index != -1) {
        subList.add(subList.get(index));
        subList.remove(index);
    }
});
```